# How do i make my bot have a random input between 1 and 100

Tags: python, discord, bots

I need help on makeing my discord bot say a number between 1 and 100? Here is my code line.

@client.command()
async def random_number(ctx):
await ctx.send("?")

Comment: `import random`, `random.randint(1, 100)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import random

@client.command()
async def random_number(ctx):
    await ctx.send(str(random.randint(1, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random    

#...

@client.command()
async def random_number(ctx):
    await ctx.send(random.randint(1, 100))
```